Ubuntu 24.04 - Headset not recognized
Recently got an HP Laptop 15-fc0002nm ProdID 7S4S8EA#BED
Ryzen 7520U with Realtek ALC236
When I plugin in my Headset, it is not recognized.
The curious thing is, when I plug in a USB sound card and unplug it, the headset is then recognized on next plug in.
After the next reboot, this procedure needs to be done again in order for the laptop to recognize the headset.
Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.
